# HttpWebClient getting hidden field data from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get the contents of the hidden field

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="kPx9IGKrVVAqqFeucPtMA23XjbP7L3gKUlGVnSRXd173frtNjADPLJu6wLoBPlxGiIcgNw2" />
```

I need to grab this value so that I can post back with the login credentials.  How can I grab this value using the HTTPClient?

Comment: Well it's within the HTML, right? So once you've got the HTML, you need to parse it and find that content...

Comment: Use this: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and parse it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (couldn't be bothered to translate to HttpClient instead of WebClient, but that's not the important bit):

```
using(var wc=new WebClient())
{
    var dom = wc.DownloadString(someUrl);
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(dom);
    var reqVerTokenElement = htmlDoc
                        .DocumentNode
                        .Descendants("input")
                        .Where(n => n.Attributes["name"]!=null 
                                    && n.Attributes["name"].Value
                                        =="__RequestVerificationToken")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    if(reqVerTokenElement!=null)
    {
        var tokenValue = reqVerTokenElement.Attributes["value"].Value;
    }
}
```